# Fitting a Time series model

Tags: time-series, arima, garch

My data set(Petrol 95 Octane) is stationary at 1st difference. Both Original data and 1st differenedata set has Heteroscedasticity. GARCH model doesn't fit to data set. Can I use ARIMA/GARCH? What are the other methods?

I checked hereroscedasticity using Evies software used R to fit GARCH.( coefficient of the model doesn't significant )
This is the time plot.
[image]

Comment: Is it price of petrol, production volume of petrol or what? Are there any stylized facts about the series that you would like to account for?

Comment: volume of demand. there isn't any factors.

Comment: What is the data frequency? Can you give more details? Could plot your data for us? How do you determine presence of heteroskedasticity? How do you know that GARCH model does not fit? (When providing more details, you should ideally edit the post rather than answer in the comments.)

Comment: I see that you edited your post including some more information, which is helpful. Could you be even more explicit and fully answer the questions in my last comment (by editing your post again)?